# Can I use Apple's SKCloudServiceController through python?

Tags: python, authentication, authorization, pyobjc, apple-music

I've been trying to construct an app (using python-flask, and react JS as a front end display) as a side project for my own practice that authenticates a user into Spotify, then takes a playlist from their library and re creates it in Apple Music. However, once I made it past Spotify authentication and using Spotify APIs to get a list of playlists and access the contents, I realized I needed a developer token and a music user token to grant access to Apple's APIs for apple music playlist creation and manipulation. The Links that describe this are posted below.

Create playlist: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemusicapi?language=data (It mentions: "This endpoint requires a music user token.")

StoreKit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit
Getting user token: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skcloudservicecontroller/2909079-requestusertokenfordevelopertoke?changes=latest_minor&language=objc

I looked in the StoreKit framework from the pyobjc library and I was unable to find the SKCloudServiceController at all, thus rendering me unable to get the user token. If anyone knows a way I can do this aside from using pyobjc, please help me out!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use this API using PyObjC (part of the "StoreKit" module installed by pyobjc-framework-StoreKit).

Note however that this API is introduced in the macOS 11 beta and is not yet available in stable release of macOS.